# Can I extend Tastypie to support Django/Postgres ArrayField?

Tags: tastypie

I am using Tastypie and djorm_pgarray.fields.ArrayField (http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2012/11/06/django-and-arrays/).

Tastypie naturally serializes it as a string like this:

```
my_array_field: "[u'Red', u'Blue', u'Yellow']"
```

But I want it to look and act like an array, not a string.

Is tastypie extensible in that way? How?  Ideally, it would be a centralized, global fix that extends the json serializer to support the ArrayField type.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best answer I've found is to do this per-field:

```
def dehydrate_my_array_field(self, bundle):
    return bundle.obj.my_array_field
```

This will at least give me the array back.

I am not using hydrate, yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to dehydrate and hydrate the field yourself.
Tastypie comes with a ListField which will do it for you. So you could do something like this:

```
mylist = fields.ListField(attribute='mylist')
```